# What's the best possible architecture for a small web application using MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc

I need to create a web application that will use MVC. The application is small, and will only use one web page. It will retrieve information from a database, as well as add and update entries onto it. The page will most probably be accessed by only one person at a time. It will not be using Entity Framework.

I'm new to MVC and I have been reading up on a lot of its material for the past weeks but I still can't decide on how I should tackle this project. The coding part is easy enough, I just don't know how to "build" it.

Initially I had planned something like using a repository, but then I encountered "service layers" and now I'm not so sure anymore (again).

What would be the best possible approach for this project? Thanks

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: @Tibo thanks for the input. I should have probably mentioned I already have codes for populating combo boxes from database written up as a test, only on my controllers. But I've read that controllers are only supposed to direct users to pages, so I figured I'd start layering my project. Does that help? If it still doesn't, I'm willing to take down my question.

Comment: Sorry, wiped my comment. Anyway: you're in the ideal situation to try and learn new things (it's a small project) . Experiment. If you want a strict MVC layering, then try and and see what happens. Once you have written a few of these apps, you'll see something that emerges - that's a pattern. But for now I suggest: keep reading but also keep experimenting on your end. This is because no one saw your project when they wrote about MVC. So you're the only one who can tell if this or that principle applies. Don't be afraid!

Comment: @Tibo thank you, I'll try my best. Would it be appropriate to delete my question, or do i leave it as it is even with the downvotes?

Comment: Dunno. I've upvoted your question because you show a good attitude and that's what this site (and our profession!) is about. However, on the long run, the question isn't very useful to the community. I hope it's been helpful to *you* - and in this regard, you may very well delete the question because you have already learned something.

Comment: @Tibo thank you again. I'll leave it be as courtesy to those who've helped me, and hopefully to show others the kind of questions one should not be asking here. I'll let the mods decide if this post goes. thanks again, have a nice day..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably suffering from "analysis paralysis". The cure is to just write the simplest thing that could probably work. Abstractions like repository and service layer etc. might not be necessary since your requirement are very simple.

You shouldn't think of patterns like repository as "things you have to do", but rather as "solutions to problems". If you don't have the problem in the first place, you probably don't need the solution. If you in the future (if the application grown and becomes more complex) realize you *do* have a problem and a repository might be a solution, then you have learned something really valuable: The context the the pattern actually is useful.